# Get / Set SystemTimeAdjustment on WinCE and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, time, windows-ce

I want to make get and set -Systemtimeadjustment to manipulate the local clock and i want to be platform independend. So how do I get the function(name) for WinCE or Linux? I searched in google but i didn´t find anything!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses the [adjtimex](http://linux.die.net/man/2/adjtimex) function (RFC 1305, David L. Mills). For details see [Linux/kernel/time/timekeeping.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c).

Answer (score 0):

The two OSes work very differently in how you set the clock, so there's no way to do it "platform independently". Arno answered how it's done in Linux.  in CE, it's done with `SetSystemTime`.  You'll have to wrap the two in logic that determines at run time which to call or with #ifdef` statement to compile the right one for the right platform.

Comment: yes i use #ifdef to decide which code(part) should be compiled. thanks for info and sorry that I didn´t metion it. I just want to know which are the function names of each platform.